# Remove bold and italic formatting when choosing heading tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, execcommand

I'm building a text editor with React and I have come up with a little problem. When I choose an h1 tag and click on "B" and "I" it is still formatting. I need to prevent it somehow or disallow formatting at all if the selected text is h1.

Button Component:

```
class Btn extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.clicked = false;
  }
  onClick = e => {
    if(this.clicked && this.props.cmd === 'heading'){
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    } else {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, this.props.arg);
      document.execCommand(this.props.cmd, false, this.props.arg);
    }
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
  }
  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.onClick} id={this.props.id}><li className={"fas fa-" + this.props.name}></li></button>;
  }
```

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vyr6344ljl

Comment: What you are asking is far from trivial and is too broad for a Stackoverflow question. There are many many text editors around you could review source code of to help you or just use one that is already battle tested and has the features you want

Comment: I suggest you check out Draft.js: https://draftjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your title and description of the problem make it very hard to be sure what you want.

However, you are storing your state in instance variables, instead of using the React `state` variable.

While I'm not sure what exactly the bug you're experiencing is, I can suggest you try the following:

```
class Btn extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { clicked: false };
  }
  onClick = e => {
    if(this.state.clicked && this.props.cmd === 'heading'){
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    } else {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, this.props.arg);
      document.execCommand(this.props.cmd, false, this.props.arg);
    }
    this.setState((state, props) => ({clicked: !state.clicked}));
  }
  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.onClick} id={this.props.id}><li className={"fas fa-" + this.props.name}></li></button>;
  }
```